# rbenv and sublime text 3

Tags: ruby, linux, rbenv

I have installed ruby using `rbenv`.  I am using sublime text 3 and a Linux Mint 17.1 system.  I am trying to build a program using `control-b`.  When I do this I get the following message:

```
/bin/bash: ruby: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: ruby "/home/christopher/projects/hello.rb"]
[dir: /home/christopher/projects]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr /games:/usr/local/games]
```

When I check my path using my terminal, I get the following:

```
/home/christopher/.rbenv/shims:/home/christopher/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local /sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

How do I get my paths to line up?

Answer (score 0):

Looking a long time for a solution to this I found the script ["Pathway"](http://robdodson.me/hacking-the-path-variable-in-sublime-text/) that gave me an idea how to fix this.

I ended adding the following `Pathway.py` file to `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/User` to set a fixed ruby version managed by `rbenv` for all my sublime sessions:

```python
import os
import subprocess

HOME = '/Users/my_user'  # <== Change this accordingly
RBENV = '/.rbenv/versions/2.5/bin'  # <== Choose version from ~/.rbenv/versions

# Sublime's default path is
# /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
os.environ['PATH'] = HOME + RBENV + ':' + os.environ['PATH']

print('[Pathway] now the PATH is = ' + os.environ['PATH'])
print('[Pathway] sublime now uses', subprocess.check_output(["which", "ruby"]))
```

Now I have a deterministic and controllable ruby version to run things in sublime

Answer (score 0):

So for "rbenv", your ruby executable is probably at "~/.rbenv/shims/ruby".  But check! (On linux, in the directory you'll be working in, at the prompt, type "which ruby".)

The default Ruby SublimeText 3 Build system may not point to the right place.

At least that's what I think the problem was for me.

Issue is, while you can (maybe should) define a new build system for Ruby, for me, that meant two Ruby build systems, as I could not figure out what to do with the old built in one.

You can change the old one easily by installing package "PackageResourceViewer" and then restarting sublime, and then command (shift-ctrl-p on linux) "PackageResourceViewer:OpenResource" and search for "Ruby", then look for the Build system.  Note I commented out stuff, and left good notes in case I need to revert.

I presume that when I next install ST3, this will be overwritten. Adding a new build system, or working with path or something is probably a better approach, but I already took to much time on this.

References
[Building Ruby and Using RVM](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/building-ruby-and-using-rvm/2731)
[SublimeText 3 Ruby Build Error](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-3-ruby-build-error/21194/8)